# change the $ sign to thai bhat in catalook in dnn

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

there is a default Dollar Sign before the every Price tag. i want to change this to Thai Bhat of thailand. How can i do it?

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear, what application is this?

Comment: i am using the Catalook in Dnn. The default Price tag is $. I want to Change it to thai baht.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question]() to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your prices are contained within a span or a div elements using a class such as:

```
<span class="pricetag">$100,00.00</span>
```

A simple fix is to use jQuery to replace $ sign with thai baht symbol.

```
$('.pricetag').text().replace('$', '฿');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are displaying the value you can achieve it by

```
NumberFormatInfo numinfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("th-TH").NumberFormat;
textbox.Text = yourvalue.ToString("c",numinfo);
```

All you need to do is refer the Thai culture when considering the value of **Price**.